# Need a regular expression for matching specific sentence format

Tags: php, javascript, regex

I need a regular expression to match a very specific sentence format. The format is as follow:

word(that can contain `,()[]&^%# and whitespace`), word(that can contain `,()[]&^%# and whitespace`), word(that can contain `,()[]&^%# and whitespace`)

So basically it's a word, word, word but every word can contain some special characters and whitespaces. Can someone help me please?

---

Those are the examples:

1. Various Artists, Total 6, I Built
   This City (Michael Mayer Mix)
2. Ada,
       Blindhouse/ Luckycharm, Luckycharm
3. Hector, Orale, Orale (Alex Picone
   Remix)

Comment: What constitutes a "word" for you? Lowercase alphabetical chars only? Words tend not to include whitespace...

Comment: Ok you're right - it's sentence, sentence, sentence then. They can be lowercase and uppercase.

Comment: I don't think your pattern is clearly described. Maybe you could post an example.

Comment: @Pavel: Then I guess what you want is EXACTLY the same as one sentence... unless these three sentences must somehow be delimited

Comment: Are the sentences separated by comma?

Comment: yes, I want to use comma as delimeter

Comment: Is there a regular character before the first word and after the last word? Can you post an example text source?

Comment: @Pavel: If comma used both in sentence and as a separator, then it's impossible to decide which is which.

Comment: I think you're right Max. I will have to look for another solution I guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use this solution :

```
/(?x)([a-z\\d\\s()[\\]&^%#\\/]+),((?1)),((?1))/i
```

This way you don't have to repeat your pattern.

[Code on ideone](http://ideone.com/s4k2g)

Comment: Wouldn't that only work if the first word was repeated three times though?

Comment: @Nev Stokes, not (see the code on ideone) it uses subpatterns. It isn't `\1`.

Comment: +1 that one's new to me. Could you provide reference? (Only found `\1` in the manual.)

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate the link. There seems to be much much more I don't know about PCRE and which isn't documented on php.net. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that you want to include the `,` that delimits your sentences in the allowed pattern. If you do want to match a sentence three times:

```
/^[a-z()[]&^%#\s]+,[a-z()[]&^%#\s]+,[a-z()[]&^%#\s]+$/i
```

Comment: I've just noticed that your second example has a / in it which doesn't match the pattern you define.

Comment: No need to escape all those characters; in character classes only `\‍` and `]` (depending on the position also `^` and `-`) are special characters that need to be escaped. So `[a-z()[\\]&^%#\s]` suffices.

Comment: Furthermore you should allow numbers. Either use `a-z0-9` or maybe better `\w`.